# DB2 Show the latest row record from users, using the date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, db2, squirrel-sql

I have 100 records from 3 users.  I want to show the most recent record from each user.  I have the following query:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Mytable  
WHERE Dateabc = CURRENT DATE 
AND timeabc =  
(
  SELECT MAX(timeabc)
  FROM Mytable
)
```

It returns the most recent record for everyone, and I need it to return most recent record from every user.

Comment: Why tag the question mySQL when you're stating db2 in the subject line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume somewhere in your table you have a userID...

```
  select userID, max(timeabc) from mytable group by userID
```

Answer (score 2):

Should the solution support both DB2 and mysql?

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable as x
WHERE Dateabc = CURRENT_DATE 
  AND timeabc = (SELECT MAX( timeabc ) FROM Mytable as y where x.user = y.user)
```

If it's only DB2 more efficient solutions exists:

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT x.*, row_number() over (partition by user order by timeabc desc) as rn 
    FROM Mytable as x
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Mytable as a
WHERE Dateabc = CURRENT_DATE 
AND timeabc =
(
    SELECT MAX( timeabc )
    FROM Mytable as b 
    WHERE a.uId = b.uId
)
```